# Failover for Windows booted from iSCSI target using ietd

Tags: windows, linux, failover, iscsi

A Windows endpoint booted over iSCSI blue-screens and reboots as soon as the failover target source comes up. Till that point, Windows appears to be "frozen". The blue screen codes are sometimes 0x00000f4 and sometimes 0x000007a. Now, on failover, the secondary maintains the same iqn and the source of the Windows disk is independent of the iSCSI target. Now when the network is disconnected for a booted endoint, the same "freeze" happens and the system resumes when the network is plugged back in. But when the target fails-over, it doesnt resume, instead blue-screens and reboots. The targets are exposed using ietd/iscsi-target on Ubuntu 8.10

Any ideas why?

Comment: You using MPIO? Software Initiator? Hardware Initiator?

Answer (score 0):

most likely problem in hardware of windows host